# Spark deploy-related properties in spark-submite

Tags: java, apache-spark

When creating a spark based java application, SparkConf is created using

```
sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTests")
                           .setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
                           .set("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
                           .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "2g");
```

But in the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), it says that

> Any values specified as flags or in the properties file will be passed on to the application and merged with those specified through SparkConf. Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the spark-defaults.conf file. A few configuration keys have been renamed since earlier versions of Spark; in such cases, the older key names are still accepted, but take lower precedence than any instance of the newer key.
>   Spark properties mainly can be divided into two kinds: one is related to deploy, like “spark.driver.memory”, “spark.executor.instances”, this kind of properties may not be affected when setting programmatically through SparkConf in runtime, or the behavior is depending on which cluster manager and deploy mode you choose, so it would be suggested to set through configuration file or spark-submit command line options; another is mainly related to Spark runtime control, like “spark.task.maxFailures”, this kind of properties can be set in either way.

So is there a list of these deploy related properties which I can only give as command line arguments in spark-submit?

It is given `local[*]` here, but in run-time we are deploying through a yarn cluster.

Comment: hello @jashan did you manage to make your configuration work properly?

Answer (score 1):

I am also not sure what the phrase:

***this kind of properties may not be affected when setting programmatically through SparkConf in runtime, or the behavior is depending on which cluster manager and deploy mode you choose, so it would be suggested to set through configuration file or spark-submit command line options; another is mainly related to Spark***

exactly means. Maybe someone can make it clear for us. Although I know that in the case of YARN the precedence goes as follows:

1. If you set the settings from you code with

   ```
   SparkSession.builder()
   .config(sparkConf)
   .getOrCreate()
   ```

   this will override all the other settings(command line, defaults.conf). The unique exception here is when you modify a
   setting after initializing your session (after calling
   session.getOrCreate). In this case it will be ignored as you can
   imagine
2. If you don't modify settings from your code it will fall back to the
   command line settings (spark will consider those
   specified in command line otherwise will load them from defaults.conf)
3. Finally if none of the above is given it will load the settings from
   defaults.conf

So my final advice would be to feel free to set settings such as *“spark.driver.memory”, “spark.executor.instances”* from your code.